# How to complete the basis for $M_{2,2}(R)$ (all real 2 by 2 matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following ordered basis

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$  $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
 $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

How to complete the basis for $M_{2,2}(R)$?

Comment: Would you be able to do it for $\Bbb{R}^4$ if the vectors were $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ (converting $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\\ d\end{bmatrix}$)?

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to complete basis for vectors there is no difference in doing it. ..

Hint: $M_{2*2}$ is the same as $R^4$. You can create a bijection between these two spaces. Completing basis in one is completing the basis in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Write down each matrix as an element in $\;\Bbb R^4\;$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow(1,1,0,0),\;\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow(1,0,1,0) ,\;\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow(1,0,1,1)$$

Form a matrix now with te above vectors as rows and try to find out a fourth vector that'll make that $\;4\times 4\;$ matrix regular, say:

$$$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}

so you need, for example, the matrix  $\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\;$.

Of course, there are infinite posibilities. Choose the simplest one you can find.